# cakephp pagination's and finds

Tags: cakephp, paginator

hi all I'm trying to have pagination in a table in one of my views, I have my find statement returning the correct set of results however I am unsure how I can make my table be able to sort the information I have found.

here is the controller, when I try paginate the find all i get is errors

```
public function index_admin(){
    //displays all disputes related to account.id
    //in a dashboard for an administrator user

    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Dispute');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.png');
    $this->layout='home_layout';

    //gets the User.account_id
    $id = $this->Auth->User('account_id');
    $conditions=array("OR"=> array(
        'Invoice.sender_id' => $id,
        'Invoice.receiver_id' => $id));

    $receiver=$this->Dispute->find('all',array(
    'conditions'=>$conditions));

    $this->set('receiver',$receiver);
    $this->paginate('Dispute'); 
    $this->set('id',$id);


}
```

here is the code for the view

```
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id', 'Invoice ID'); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('dispute_date', 'Dispute Created'); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('status', 'Status'); ?></th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>

    <?php foreach($receiver as $receivers):?>

    <tr>
        </tr><tr>
        <td><?php echo $receivers['Invoice']['id'] ;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $receivers['Dispute']['dispute_date'] ;?></td>

    <?php

    if($receivers['Dispute']['active']==1)
    {
        $status = 'Active';
        $bgcol = '#B9FAEA';
    }
    else 
    {
        $status = 'Resolved';
        $bgcol = '#FAB9B9';
    } 
    ?><td align='center' bgcolor='<?php echo $bgcol ?>'><?php echo $status ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->Html->link('View',
                                array('controller' => 'Messages','action'=>'viewMessage_admin',$receivers['Dispute']['id'])); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->Html->link('Resolve',
                                array('controller' => 'Disputes','action'=>'resolve',$receivers['Dispute']['id'])); ?></td>
    </tr>


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `paginate` instead of `find`, not after it:

```
$id = $this->Auth->User('account_id');
$conditions=array("OR"=> array(
    'Invoice.sender_id' => $id,
    'Invoice.receiver_id' => $id));

$receiver=$this->paginate('Dispute', $conditions);
$this->set('receiver',$receiver);
$this->set('id',$id);
```

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP reference for pagination in controller side as wee as on view side so it will give you deep knowledge in paginator of cakePHP

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html
http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1233/Pagination-in-Views

example
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/rtconner/2007/06/13/basic-pagination-overview-1-2